# can not reload server with tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I created a web application using eclipse and Tomcat 7 I had the following code in the html file and the java servlet class 
in the html file:

```
<form action="UserAccessServlet" method = "get">
```

in the servlet class I had

```
@WebServlet ("/UserAccessServlet")
```

then I just made some small changes (new println statements) but it shows no effect I changed the server name with the following peice of code

html file:  `<form action="SQA_Servlet" method = "get">`
java class: `@WebServlet ("/SQA_Servlet")`

but it seems that no reload take place and I got the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SQA_Learning/SQA_Servlet

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /SQA_Learning/SQA_Servlet

description The requested resource (/SQA_Learning/SQA_Servlet) is not available.
```

I tried clean the module, refresh, close the reopen the project with the same result

I replaced  `@WebServlet ("/SQA_Servlet")`  with `@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/SQA_Servlet"})`

and still have no effect.. any suggestion.

Comment: I'm still waiting for suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [http status 404 : the required resource is not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786857/http-status-404-the-required-resource-is-not-found)

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763588/http-status-404-server-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify this in your `@WebServlet` tag:

```
@WebServlet(name="UserAccessServlet", urlPatterns="/SQA_Servlet")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem, and I deleted web.xml .
after that, I get the right result.

Another way add `metadata-complete="true"` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"
    metadata-complete="true">

</web-app>
```