# http status 404 : the required resource is not found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, tomcat, java-server

I creat a web application using eclipse and tomcat7 I had the following code in the html file and the java servlet class 
in the html file:

```
<form action="UserAccessServlet" method = "get">
```

in the servlet class I had

```
@WebServlet ("/UserAccessServlet")
```

then I just made some small changes (new println statements) but it shows no effect I changed the server name with the following peice of code

html file:  `<form action="SQA_Servlet" method = "get">`
java class: `@WebServlet ("/SQA_Servlet")`

but it seems that no reload take place and I got the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SQA_Learning/SQA_Servlet

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /SQA_Learning/SQA_Servlet

description The requested resource (/SQA_Learning/SQA_Servlet) is not available.
```

I tried clean the module, refresh, close the reopen the project with the same result

I replaced  `@WebServlet ("/SQA_Servlet")`  with `@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/SQA_Servlet"})`

and still have no effect.. any suggestion.

Comment: Would this help? http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg15886.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [http status 404 : server not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763588/http-status-404-server-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The `WebServlet` `name` attribute cannot start with a `/`. Rather do,

```
@WebServlet("UserAccessServlet")
```

or leave it blank (if you want the `WebServlet` to use the name of your Servlet class name. Example:

```
@WebServlet
public class UserAccessServlet extends HttpServlet {


//Do stuff
}
```

I would **recommend** declaring your `WebServlet` annotations fully like in [this example](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet3/webservlet-annotation-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when and in what for conditions you are receiving this error. But if you are deploying to tomcat, the following might occur:

Assuming your webapp is called "my.webapp" resulting in my.webapp.war
assuming you have a Servlet "servlet1" which performs action1 => `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/action1")`  (note the slash in front of action1)

Assuming you are calling this action with a html form:
`<form action="/action1" method="GET">` this might not work because of the slash in front of action1

When it's there tomcat will redirect to localhost:8080/action1?..
while it should redirect to localhost:8080/my.project/action1?..

Solution alter the html so the form looks like:
`<form action="action1" method="GET">`, don't change the `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/action1")`

Hope this helps someone!